# How can I delay execution of Javascript string templates so as to read and interpolate them from an external module?

Tags: javascript, string, templates, ecmascript-6

I have a bunch of these in a module separate from my execution code:

```
const warnings = {
  functionDoesNotReturnValue: {
    message: `${name} did not return a value`,
    get: (name) => {
      return {
        action: warnings.functionDoesNotReturnValue.action,
        message: `'${name}' did not return a value`,
      };
    },
  },
```

I currently have the `get` method added, which just provides the interpolation string required and applies it to a copy of `message` within the function.

But I would like to remove the redundant `get` function entirely and supply the provided `name` parameter directly to the `message` property as required, since every warning currently needs its own redundant get method, which simply contains copy of the `message` property and returns the interpolated version, purely so that execution of the string template may be deferred until the time `get` is run.

I can't figure out how to do this via tag methods: whatever happens, the template string appears to evaluate the as soon as the program is run. Any suggestions on a more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: The `message` property is just a string, the template literal has already been evaluated at that point. If you want to delay processing, that's what functions are for. Why do you have the `message` property at all? It doesn't seem to do anything in this context. Why not have `functionDoesNotReturnValue` be a function?

Comment: Well yes, the message property is an exact duplicate of the get method at present - I am currently using the `get` method, and not the `message` property at all.  I was just showing both simultaneously to indicate that `get` was what I was currently using, but `message` was how I wanted it to be via a tag function or something. The suggested answer does answer my question - in a word, no, I can't make a reusable template literal. Apologies, I spent some time looking but couldn't find that accepted answer.